# multihomed router for small business

Tags: router, multi-homed

Okay, I have 5 external IP addresses.  I need to figure out how to all those IPs to point to a set of particular machines behind my firewall.  3 are going to one machine.

My router only appears to support a single ISP provided IP.

As I'd rather not spend thousands of dollars, what are my options?

Could I plug a switch in and have multiple routers hanging off of it?  Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab pfSense + ALIX kit from [Netgate.com](http://Netgate.com).  It supports virtual IPs and NAT 1:1 (plus VLANs if you're interested in that) so you can use your public IPs on one physical interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 5 public IP addresses that are not owned by your ISP you will have to make arrangements for the ISP to route those.  Good luck with that.

The key is public IP addresses.

Comment: These were assigned by the ISP.

Comment: Router Mfg. and Model?

Comment: I just installed the router given to me by my service provider.  It has these features.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on ADSL, have a look at the Draytek 2820 router. Supports multiple public IPs and is a breeze to setup. About 140UK Pounds.